# How do you formulate n-ary product and sum types in this typed lambda calculus universe?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, algebraic-data-types, gadt, data-kinds

Here is the code where I'm having an issue:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, LANGUAGE DataKinds #-} 

-- * Universe of Terms * -- 

type Id = String 

data Term a where 
   Var :: Id -> Term a
   Lam :: Id -> Type -> Term b -> Term (a :-> b)
   App :: Term (a :-> b) -> Term a -> Term b 
   Let :: Id -> Term a -> Term b -> Term b 

   Tup :: Term a -> Term b -> Term (a :*: b)   -- * existing tuple
   Lft :: Term a -> Term (a :+: b)   -- * existing sum 
   Rgt :: Term b -> Term (a :+: b)

   Tru :: Term Boolean
   Fls :: Term Boolean
   Bot :: Term Unit

-- * Universe of Types * --

data Type = Type :-> Type | Type :*: Type | Type :+: Type | Boolean | Unit
```

So I want to extend `Tup` to be defined over arbitrarily many arguments, same with sum. But a formulation involving lists would constrain the the final Term to one type of a:

```
Sum :: [Term a] -> Term a
```

I could just get rid of the `a` and do something like:

```
Sum :: [Term] -> Term
```

But then I lose the very things I'm trying to express.

So how do I express some polymorphic Term without loss of expressiveness?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you want to sum `Term`s of different types, but the title of the question suggests you want to form a sum *type*.  So what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Why not just use binary sums and products? Your `Tup` is already forming a product type. Similarly, you could have `Lft :: Term a -> Term (a :+: b)` and `Rgt :: Term b -> Term (a :+: b)` for a binary sum type. And add `Type :+: Type` to your universe of types, of course.

Comment: What @kosmikus said, and add `Unt :: Term Unit` if you want a unit for your product.

Comment: @kosmikus I wanted to generalize the `Tup` to one of arbitrarily many arguments, and similarly a `Sum` that's not restricted to two arguments

Comment: @kosmikus I updated the title to better reflect my question

Comment: @chibro2 but right now you need witnesses of both types to construct a Sum; this is not how it is usually defined. Usually Sum requires a witness of _either_ of the types. Hence the need for Lft and Rgt in kosmikus solution

Comment: @SassaNF ahh thank you. I was not aware of such subtleties but thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doing this for a "list" is tricky using Haskell's type system, but can be done. As a starting point, it's easy enough if you restrict yourself to binary products and sums (and personally, I'd just stick with this):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, TypeOperators, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies #-} 

import Prelude hiding (sum) -- for later

-- * Universe of Terms * -- 

type Id = String 

data Term :: Type -> * where 
   Var :: Id -> Term a
   Lam :: Id -> Type -> Term b -> Term (a :-> b)
   App :: Term (a :-> b) -> Term a -> Term b 

   Let :: Id -> Term a -> Term b -> Term b 
   Tup :: Term a -> Term b -> Term (a :*: b) -- for binary products
   Lft :: Term a -> Term (a :+: b) -- new for sums
   Rgt :: Term b -> Term (a :+: b) -- new for sums
   Tru :: Term Boolean
   Fls :: Term Boolean
   Uni :: Term Unit -- renamed

-- * Universe of Types * --

data Type = Type :-> Type | Type :*: Type | Type :+: Type | Boolean | Unit | Void
  -- added :+: and Void for sums
```

To build an arbitrary-length sum type, we need an environment of terms. That's
a heterogeneous list indexed by the types of the terms in it:

```
data Env :: [Type] -> * where
   Nil   :: Env '[]
   (:::) :: Term t -> Env ts -> Env (t ': ts)

infixr :::
```

We then use a type family to collapse a list of types into a binary product type.
Alternatively, we could add something like `Product [Type]` to the `Type` universe.

```
type family TypeProd (ts :: [Type]) :: Type
type instance TypeProd '[]       = Unit
type instance TypeProd (t ': ts) = t :*: TypeProd ts
```

The `prod` functions collapses such an environment to applications of `Tup`. Again, you
could also add `Prod` as a constructor of this type to the `Term` datatype.

```
prod :: Env ts -> Term (TypeProd ts)
prod Nil        = Uni
prod (x ::: xs) = x `Tup` prod xs
```

Arbitrary-length sums only take a single element to inject, but need a tag to indicate
into which type of the sum to inject it:

```
data Tag :: [Type] -> Type -> * where
   First :: Tag (t ': ts) t
   Next  :: Tag ts s -> Tag (t ': ts) s
```

Again, we have a type family and a function to build such a beast:

```
type family TypeSum (ts :: [Type]) :: Type
type instance TypeSum '[]       = Void
type instance TypeSum (t ': ts) = t :+: TypeSum ts

sum :: Tag ts t -> Term t -> Term (TypeSum ts)
sum First    x = Lft x
sum (Next t) x = Rgt (sum t x)
```

Of course, lots of variations or generalizations are possible, but this should give you
an idea.